# Redux-Form - Validation function causes infinite loop

Tags: redux-form

I have redux-form and I have a problem with the validation function. And this error only happens on my cloud servers, in local, I have no problems with this.

Here is the validation function :

```
function validate(values){
    const errors = {};
    let requiredFields = [
        'gender', 'first_name', 'last_name'
    ];
    requiredFields.forEach(field => {
        if (!values[field]) {
            errors[field] = 'Required';
        }
    });
    return errors;
}
```

And I call it just like this :

```
EditProfileForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'editProfile',
    validate
})(EditProfileForm);
```

And even when I run the production code in local, which for now simply does :

```
config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: false
    })
)
```

It still works in local, it's only when the code is on the servers that I have the problem.

It dispatches the action : redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS to the infinite and I have to force shut down Chrome to stop this.

I have initialValues that is an object, and the error occurs only when values are empty, ie the DB doesn't return me the `first_name` for instance however. I don't understand why it's looping like this, and only on the cloud.

I also tried to set `first_name`to undefined if it's not setted in DB, but still not ok.

The version of redux-form used is `6.4.2`

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What's in the payload of the `UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS` action? Can you inspect that?

Comment: The answer in the payload tells me that the field are empty... 
Maybe the problem is because of the initialValues props that I pass to my Component ? This page http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/initializeFromState/ tells that I have to connect to reducers...